# How to swap items quickly with stash (6-slotted Tinker)?

Tags: dota-2

Late game Tinker has more than 6 items but still needs to keep bottle and soul ring in Stash in order to heal quicker in Fountain. However, to do this I need to swap out my current items with the stashed items quickly.

What's the best way to do this? In this [Dendi's Tinker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXbFK7Gph1E), he seems able to do it without having the mouse over the item, so I guess there must be a hotkey somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't shift queue an item swap because of the mechanic of the stash (you can interact with it only when you are in the fountain area). The best way to do it quickly is to swap it by drag & dropping the item you want to swap in your inventory on the one you want in your stash (or the other way arround). This is the way [Dendi does it](http://youtu.be/BXbFK7Gph1E?t=8m1s).

**However**, you can shift-queue to drop the item from your inventory (by drag and dropping them to the ground) while you are teleporting to the fountain. If you do this with your Dagon or Scythe of Vyse you'll regenerate your mana quickly and manage your time at the fountain better.

Comment: And by "the command" you mean: click on item in slot and drag them over the item in stash?

Comment: In the video the mouse action really does not line up with the item swap though, don't you think?

Comment: @Heisenberg yes the fact that the item doesnt swap look like a replay gltich when in player perspective

Comment: Just be careful of dropping items on the ground, or things like this can happen. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2EI_zZNhM4

Comment: OK I was a little to quick on the comment there. I cannot control the exact position of the mouse.